# static <T extends Number & Comparable<? super Number>>

Tags: java, generics, methods, static, call

I have following class with one static method:

```
public class Helper {

    public static <T extends Number & Comparable<? super Number>> Boolean inRange(T value, T minRange, T maxRange) {
        //  equivalent (value >= minRange && value <= maxRange)
        if (value.compareTo(minRange) >= 0 && value.compareTo(maxRange) <= 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

I try to call this method:

```
Integer value = 2;
Integer min = 3;
Integer max = 8;
Helper.inRange(value, min, max) ;
```

Netbeans compiler show me this error message:

> method inRange in class Helper cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: T,T,T
>     found: java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer
>     reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
>       inferred: java.lang.Integer
>       bound(s): java.lang.Number,java.lang.Comparable

Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>`.

E.g. `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`, which is not compatible with `Comparable<? super Number>` (Integer is not a superclass of Number). `Comparable<? extends Number>` would not work either because Java would then think the `?` could be any subclass of `Number`, and passing a `T` to `compareTo` would then not compile because it expects a parameter of `?`, not `T`.

*Edit:* as newacct said, `<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>>` will work too (and be slightly more general) since then `compareTo` will then accept any `?` of which `T` is a subclass, and as usual, an instance of a subclass can be given as a parameter where a superclass is expected.

Comment: for best results, use `<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>>`